# Load file based on URL regx in IIS from different document root

Tags: nginx, iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

Please share suggestions for below issue, How to handle an IIS URL rewrite
I want to load js file from a different document root

eg `localhost:80/apps/abcd.js`

This file is located in a different folder path
So a rule to load all `/apps/(.*)` from C://JSAssets/

Below rule throws 503 error

---

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule5" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="apps/(.*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="C:\JSAssets/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

---

Working Nginx code sample

```
  location /apps {
    root /var/web;
    try_files /root/assets$uri /public$uri =404;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS support only 1 document root. To add additional physical paths use virtual directory. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory